# Android - dragging imageview with finger does not update position

Tags: android, touch, imageview

I'm using a frame layout and a top/left margin combination to drag an imageview around the screen. I've added all code in setOnTouchListener() of the imageview. The problem is the UI does not get repainted on MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE and i only see the update when MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is received. How could i force the view to redraw the image at its new position on MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE ?

Answer (score 1):

You want to invalidate the view.  If you can get the ImageView call getParent() then invalidate on the parent and that should force a redraw.

```
((View)v.getParent()).invalidate();
```

Comment: Yep, that's what i thought as well, but didn't work. I actually found the framelayout containing this imageview by id and called invalidate on it. So far the only working solution is re-assigning imageBitmap to the imageview, but that sounds way too lame to be a permanent solution.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot, I had a similar problem and this solution worked for me. The question is why? Is this a bug in Android? Shouldn't `imageView.invalidate()` be enough to redraw the image? What is also interesting is the fact that in my case bare `imageView.invalidate()` is enough to redraw the view in Android 2.3 but in Android 4.0 it is not.